# Passing parameter for using same data for two views

Tags: php, laravel

I have this controller method:

```
public function index() {

        if(Auth::user()){

            $tests = $this->getAllTests();

            $tests = (new TestDetailsController)->getTestDetails($tests);

            return view('website.home')->with(['tests' => $tests]);
    }else{
        return view('website.auth.login');
    }   
}
```

And this is the route:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

I am displaying this on the view `home.blade.php` just fine, but I need this same data with this route somehow to display on two views.
For example in home.blade.php and on another view.
 How is this possible? Should I pass a parameter or something? 
Can you please help me I am new to coding.. Thanks.

Comment: You answered your question. A conditional parameter should be passed to the controller to decide which view that should be returned! This is the pure logic.

Comment: Yea but I dont know how can you help me with an example please?

Comment: Checkout the following answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may access your action using the following two URIs:

1. `/home`
2. `/home?view2=yes`

So your action return view should looks like:

```
....
$tests = (new TestDetailsController)->getTestDetails($tests);

if (is_null(request('view2',null))){
       return view('website.home')->with(['tests' => $tests]);
}
else{
     return view('website.another-view')->with(['tests' => $tests]);
}
....
```

Also, in this way, you may able to render as many as views you are want, not only two:

```
....
    $tests = (new TestDetailsController)->getTestDetails($tests);
    $viewsList = ['webmite.view1','posts.listings','users.found'];
    if (!is_null(request('view2',null)) && isset($viewsList[request('view2')])){
           return view($viewsList[request('view2')])->with(['tests' => $tests]);
    }
    else{

return view('website.home')->with(['tests' => $tests]);
    }
    ....
```

However, in this way the `view2` parameter should be an integer equals to the desired view index in `$viewsList`. i.e `/home?view2=0`

Comment: Thank you very much, and then on view blade should I write @if(view2 == null) or something else

Comment: I mean the link <a href="@if(view2 == null)" </a>

Comment: @LOLA in the view you are able to use the `request()` helper also typically like the controller's action!

Answer (score 1):

You can use view composer for that and attach it to these two views.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers):

> You may attach a view composer to multiple views at once by passing an array of views as the first argument to the composer method:

```
View::composer(
    ['home', 'another_view'],
    'App\Http\ViewComposers\MyViewComposer'
);
```

You can also [use a service class](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#business-logic-should-be-in-service-class) as I'm showing in my repo. In this case, you can do something like this in both controller methods:

```
return view('website.home', ['tests' => $this->myService->getTests()]);
```